# BroadcastReceiver not being called when pressing Notification Button

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

Inside the `onCreate` method of my `Service` I create a notification by doing the following:

```
String channelId = "001";
String channelName = "myChannel";

NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (manager != null) {
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    Notification notification;

    Intent myIntent = new Intent("alarmReceiver");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(
            Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp),
            "action string",
            pendingIntent).build();


    //Modify notification badge
    notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId).setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .addAction(action)
            .build();

    startForeground(101, notification);
}
```

The `alarmReceiver` in the `Intent` above is registered in my manifest as shown below (I did the following after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717574/5550161) question):

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="alarmReceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and here is my `AlarmReceiver` class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("onReceive - ","was called");
    }
}
```

The notification is shown, as well as the button, but when I press the button nothing happens.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: may be `onReceive()` of receiver get called checked logs.

Comment: Also register _.AlarmReceiver_ with full package name

Comment: @KalpeshKulye I checked the logs, it doesn't get called.

Comment: @Piyush I changed it to full package name, it still doesn't get called

Comment: instead of `action` put `pendingIntent` at `addAction()` might help you

Comment: @KalpeshKulye https://stackoverflow.com/q/35647821/8199772

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016426/receiving-broadcast-from-notification-on-android-oreo

Comment: @AshokKumar the issue in that question is that OP used `intent.setAction("com.example.app.intent.action.BUTTON_CLICK");` instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActionReceiver.class);`. It might be a similar issue but not the same question.

Comment: In your case also try removing intent filter from broadcast receiver in manifest file.

Comment: @AshokKumar I tried removing the intent, but still `onReceive` is still not being called

Answer (score 0):

Set PendingIntent to foreground service, And potentially add a flag:

```
FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getForegroundService(this, 0, myIntent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Your broadcast is `Implicit`, so if you want to use `getBroadcast()` it may be best to `Explicitly` declare the receiver by providing the intent with the `componentName` of the receiver.

eg:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename","fully qualified class name"));
```

---

Have you declared the service in your manifest?

Comment: Try rebooting device after switching to getForegroundService

Comment: I rebooted the device, I tried changing `Intent myIntent = new Intent("alarmReceiver");` too `Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);` and yes it is declared in my manifest otherwise the notification would not even show.

Comment: If you can post the whole classes involved might be easier to debug

Comment: I found the issue, I will provide an answer later today. Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer.